# iOS 7 auto brightness is overruling apps screen brightness setting

Tags: ios, brightness

I have an iOS 7 app where I want to make the screen darker. I am adjusting the screen brightness using the following line:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0.3;
```

This dims the screen as I expect, but if a user has auto brightness enabled the screen sometimes goes back to its original setting. Is there a way to disable auto brightness while in my app, or do I need to subscribe to the UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification notification and just reset the brightness each time it is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the auto brightness at all, so you will have to subscribe to the notification. Read more about available methods in UIScreen:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness
- [How to turn off Auto-Brightness programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782700/how-to-turn-off-auto-brightness-programatically)
- [Does iOS send notifications when the system changes the screen brightness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719443/does-ios-send-notifications-when-the-system-changes-the-screen-brightness)